# ArcGIS Intersect not showing on all street intersections

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, intersect, streets

I have a centerline shapefile and have extracted a lane way feature class from it as I am attempting to show all intersections where these lane ways cross with public roads.

I utilized the intersect tool, set output to "point", JOIN attributes to ALL and ran the tool. I noticed that not all points were showing, reran Intersect with JOIN attributes as: ONLY_FID, NO_FID and have the same results.

I am new to more complicated GIS.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. All graphics should always be embedded in the question, since links to external sites fail over time, harming the integrity of the Question. There is an icon for adding image in the editor page.

Comment: Please upload a screenshot from the layers

Comment: Have you tried increasing your XY Tolerance? Perhaps some points are not getting picked up as they are not directly over a center line

Comment: I did increase my XY tolerance, unfortunately that did not correct anything.